# XML PHP Format Setup

Tags: php, xml

Is there a why to do this? I'm new on create DomDocument. Thank you

`<!DOCTYPE Data SYSTEM "http://data.data.org/schemas/data/1.234.1/data.dtd"> <Data payloadID = "123123123131231232323" timestamp = "2015-06-10T12:59:09-07:00">`

```
$aribaXML = new DOMImplementation;
    $dtd = $aribaXML->createDocumentType('cXML', '', 'http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd');
    $dom = $aribaXML->createDocument('', '', $dtd);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways in DOM to create a new document in PHP. If you don't need the DTD you can directly create an instance of the `DOMDocument` class.

```
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', "UTF-8");
$document->appendChild(
  $cXML = $document->createElement('cXML')
);
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cXML/>
```

For a document with a DTD your approach was correct.

```
$implementation = new DOMImplementation;
$dtd = $implementation->createDocumentType(
    'cXML', '', 'http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd'
);
$document = $implementation->createDocument("", "cXML", $dtd);
$document->encoding = 'UTF-8';
$cXML = $document->documentElement;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd">
```

After the initial bootstrap you use methods of the `$document` to create nodes and append them.

```
// set an attribute on the document element
$cXML->setAttribute('version', '1.1.007');
// xml:lang is a namespaced attribute in a reserved namespace
$cXML->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace', 'xml:lang', 'en-US');

// nested elements
// create a node, store it for the next call and append it
$cXML->appendChild(
  $header = $document->createElement('Header')
);
$header->appendChild(
  $from = $document->createElement('From')
);
$from->appendChild(
  $credential = $document->createElement('Credential')
);

// "Identity" has only a text node so we don't need to store it for later
$credential->appendChild(
  $document->createElement('Identity')
)->textContent = '83528721';

// format serialized XML string
$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd">
<cXML version="1.1.007" xml:lang="en-US">
  <Header>
    <From>
      <Credential>
        <Identity>83528721</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </From>
  </Header>
</cXML>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = new DomDocument('1.0');
$xml->formatOutput = true;

$works = $xml->createElement("works");
$xml->appendChild($works);

$work = $xml->createElement("work");
$work->setAttribute("id",1);
$works->appendChild($work);

$xml->save("storage/document.xml") or die("Error, Unable to create XML File");
```